# Post Multipart with text and file

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to send a file from my app to a webservice and for this I have to write a code who featured as this form :

```html
<form action="/api/v1/photo.json" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="udid">UDID:</label> <input type="text" name="udid" id="udid" value="web "/><br />
<label for="file">File:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
<label for="movie">Movie:</label> <input type="file" name="movie" id="movie" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

I already have the picture in a byte[], but all the things I tried return me an internal error 500 :/